# Is testing in Create-React-App handled automatically or do I need to create/import custom testing?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, eslint, create-react-app

I'm using create-react-app to build my app. Do I need to do any custom testing or is it all handled by create-react-app?

Also, do the errors and prompts I receive in my terminal and console cover all testing or is there something else I need to do before releasing an app  for production.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by testing…

If you mean unit tests, then no. create-react-app can't automatically test your application for you. It has no idea what you're trying to acomplish with your application, so it can't test it.

Or are you talking about build warnings and errors? In that case create-react-app will tell you what it is able to gather, which should be quite a bit, but it can't find possible runtime errors.

In any case if you want your whole applications functionality covered by tests, you need to write those yourself. If you're not familiar with testing in general you may want to have a look at one or more react unit testing articles (https://felixgerschau.com/unit-testing-react-introduction/ could be starting point) and depending on what you want looking into e2e tests could also be worthwhile.